# PA can define 6's multiplier?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let set A be : {6, 36, 216, 1296 .....}

i.e.  A={ $6^k$} where $k \in \mathbb{n} $

In the Model PA, can PA define set A?

I know PA can define set { $2^k$} and set { $3^k$}. However what about { $6^k$} ?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Yes, show that the partial function "$k$ is the unique number such that $2^k=x$", is definable (and similarly with $3^k$).

**ANOTHER HINT:** Show that the relation $x=6^k$ is definable by recursion (on $k$).

Comment: Sorry @Asaf Karagila. I don't understand your argument. I must use Peano Arithmetic.

Comment: Sorry @HoCheolSHIN. I don't understand your comment. I did give you a hint on how to use basic properties of Peano Arithmetic; and in case that you already know that recursive sets are definable in $\sf PA$, then the second hint is also helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know "Recursive sets are definable in PA." Now I know it.